# Optimization of CodeWars Python 3.6 code: Integers: Recreation One

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

I need help optimizing my python 3.6 code for the CodeWars Integers: Recreation One Kata.

We are given a range of numbers and we have to return the number and the sum of the divisors squared that is a square itself.

"Divisors of 42 are : 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42. These divisors squared are: 1, 4, 9, 36, 49, 196, 441, 1764. The sum of the squared divisors is 2500 which is 50 * 50, a square!

Given two integers m, n (1 <= m <= n) we want to find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square. 42 is such a number."

My code works for individual tests, but it times out when submitting:

```
def list_squared(m, n):
    sqsq = []
    for i in range(m, n):
        divisors = [j**2 for j in range(1, i+1) if i % j == 0]
        sq_divs = sum(divisors)
        sq = sq_divs ** (1/2)
        if int(sq) ** 2 == sq_divs:
            sqsq.append([i, sq_divs])

    return sqsq
```

Comment: I see a minor speed improvement using `j*j` rather than `j**2`.  E.g.: `python3 -m timeit 'for i in range(1,1000): [j*j for j in range(1, i+1) if i % j == 0]'`, but try it yourself.

Comment: And another tiny improvement using `sq = sq_divs ** 0.5`

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce complexity of loop in list comprehension from `O(N)` to `O(Log((N))` by setting the max range to `sqrt(num)+1` instead of `num`.

By looping from *1 to sqrt(num)+1*, we can conclude that if *i* (current item in the loop) is a factor of *num* then *num divided by i* must be another one.

Eg: 2 is a factor of 10, so is 5 (10/2)

The following code passes all the tests:

```
import math

def list_squared(m, n):
    result = []
    for num in range(m, n + 1):
        divisors = set()
        for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(num)+1)):
            if num % i == 0:
                divisors.add(i**2)
                divisors.add(int(num/i)**2)
        total = sum(divisors)
        sr = math.sqrt(total)
        if sr - math.floor(sr) == 0:
            result.append([num, total])
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more the math issue. Two maximum divisors for **i** is **i** itself and **i/2**. So you can speed up the code twice just using `i // 2 + 1` as the range stop instead of `i + 1`. Just don't forget to increase `sq_divs` for `i ** 2`.
You may want to get some tiny performance improvements excluding `sq` variable and `sq_divs ** (1/2)`.

BTW you should use n+1 stop in the first range.

```
def list_squared(m, n):
    sqsq = []
    for i in range(m, n+1):
        divisors = [j * j for j in range(1, i // 2 + 1 #speed up twice
            ) if i % j == 0]
        sq_divs = sum(divisors)
        sq_divs += i * i #add i as divisor
        if ((sq_divs) ** 0.5) % 1 == 0: #tiny speed up here
            sqsq.append([i, sq_divs])
    return sqsq
```

UPD: I've tried the Kata and it's still timeout. So we need even more math! If **i** could be divided by **j** then it's also could be divided by **i/j** so we can use **sqrt(i)** (`int(math.sqrt(i)) + 1)`) as the range stop. `if i % j == 0` then append `j * j` to divisors array. AND `if i / j != j` then append `(i / j) ** 2`.